# Procesing image in Labview using a dll in c

Tags: c, dll, labview

I have a image in Labview I want this image as an input in my DLL in C but I don not know how to read every pixel to process the image. What I want to do is to pass the whole image to the DLL.

I have a cluster with the pixel pointer of the image, the size of the pixel and the size of the image.

[image: block diagram image]

This is the function in my DLL. `a` should contain the blue value of pixel `[i][j]`.

```
DLLIMPORT int funcImage(int *pixel_pointer, int line_width, int pixel_size, int x_resolution, int y_resolution)
{
int j;
int i;
unsigned char b;
unsigned char g;
unsigned char r;
int gray[1000][100];

for(j = 0;j < y_resolution;j++){
    for(i = 0;i < x_resolution;i++){
        b = pixel_pointer[3*i + x_resolution*j] ;
        g = pixel_pointer[3*i + 1 + x_resolution*j];
        r = pixel_pointer[3*i + 2 + x_resolution*j];
        //gray[i][j] = ((int)r)* 0.3 + ((int)g)* 0.58 + ((int)b)* 0.11;
    }
}
int a;
b = pixel_pointer[3*14*648 + 3*21 - 2];
a = (int)b;

return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

Change int *pixel_pointer to unsigned char *, and use the linewidth to adress the pixels instead of the x_resolution

```
DLLIMPORT int funcImage(unsigned char *pixel_pointer, int line_width, int pixel_size, int x_resolution, int y_resolution)
{
int j;
int i;
unsigned char b;
unsigned char g;
unsigned char r;
int gray[1000][100];

for(j = 0;j < y_resolution;j++){
    for(i = 0;i < x_resolution;i++){
        b = pixel_pointer[3*i + line_width*j] ;
        g = pixel_pointer[3*i + 1 + line_width*j];
        r = pixel_pointer[3*i + 2 + line_width*j];
        //gray[i][j] = ((int)r)* 0.3 + ((int)g)* 0.58 + ((int)b)* 0.11;
    }
}
int a;
b = pixel_pointer[3*14*648 + 3*21 - 2];
a = (int)b;

return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create dll wrapper  also you have to use image to array vi to insert image data inside your dll you can call dll in labview it is easy you can search in net to find how